# Not able to route with Query Parameters in routeProvider with AngularJS 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was developing a project with AngularJS 1 as my frontend fw, and until and unless I did not utilized the routeProvider to make it an SPA, everything was working fine. But now I am not able to route to my specifically created route.

To add more to the problem, I have this URL for instance

```
http://www.myblog.com/d?llh=12343434
```

If you notice the last part of the URL, the "llh" variable, it is a security measured imposed to check the session activity by the URL.(But that is purely backend, and it works fine)

```
.config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider','$locationProvider','base_url',function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider,base_url){
            $routeProvider
            .when("/d/:llh", {
                template: "<h4>Hello World</h4>",
                controller: "manageDistributions"
            })
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }])
```

Comment: Did you include ui.router as dependency injection within your app module?

Comment: No, I actually don't want to include the UI_router here. As I want to get the query param from the back-end to verify the "LLH" after the page is refreshed

Comment: Try to remove de last slash im your route. "/d?:llh"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with defining the route as

[image]

instead of 
[image]